# How to convert java multiclass applet to html file

Tags: java, html, object, jar, applet

Hey I've got three java classes (saved as .java) forming an applet, and have no clue how to convert it to html. I've seen people say to convert it to a .jar, but i don't know how to do that. can anyone give a step by step? (preferably using netbeans)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[making a jar file](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html)

And add this to your html file

```html
<applet code = 'packagename.ClassName' 
    archive = 'JarFileName.jar'
    width = 300
    height = 300>
</applet>
```